# How to apply css on acefaces datatable and also minimize its width

Tags: css, jsf-2, icefaces-3

Here is my `acefaces datatable`

```
<ace:dataTable id="tbl" value="#{mainSearch.searchResult}" var="srvc" 
            paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="10" 
            emptyMessage="No Record Present Yet" rowsPerPageTemplate="10,25,50,100" 
            rowIndexVar="row" rowStyleClass="#{row mod 2 eq 0?'none':'skyBlue'}">

    <ace:column headerText="Category" sortBy="#{srvc.groupName}" 
            filterBy="#{srvc.groupName}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{srvc.groupName}"/>
    </ace:column>

    <ace:column  headerText="Service Number" sortBy="#{srvc.serviceNumber}" 
            filterBy="#{srvc.serviceNumber}"filterMatchMode="contains">                            
        <h:outputText value="#{srvc.serviceNumber}"/>                       
    </ace:column>

    <ace:column headerText="Shift" sortBy="#{srvc.shift}" 
            filterBy="#{srvc.shift}" filterMatchMode="contains">
        <h:outputText value="#{srvc.shift}"/>
    </ace:column>
</ace:dataTable>
```

Now this datatable is showing on my whole page.I can fix its height by `<ace:datatable height=..` but I didn't find any width attribute.I also tried to set its width **using CSS (using style attribute on both header, datatable) but it didn't work.** Now I am stuck here and unable to find that How can I minimize its width.
**Note:** The only way that worked for me was to small the header text.For instance, As my first row header is *Category*.Now If I repalced it with just *CAT* then whole row gets shrink.It mean first of all I need to squeez the text(as it is my guess).Is there anyway that without poking this text? If not, then how can I resize this text and shortened this datatable?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried altering CSS `width` property in Firefox of the [ICEfaces showcase](http://icefaces-showcase.icesoft.org/showcase.jsf?grp=aceMenu&exp=dataTableBean), achieving the result you want. Note that there may be some potential problems when you make the table too small and the data won't fit in the table anymore, so my advice will be to inspect the resultant table in the browser to get the right CSS fixture.

Regarding the documentation of [`<ace:dataTable>`](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v3_latest/ace/tld/ace/dataTable.html), there are the typical `styleClass` and `style` property for setting CSS style classes and inline style respectively, so the following will do the work:

```
<ace:dataTable style="width:80%"> ... </ace:dataTable>
```

or

```
<ace:dataTable styleClass="my-width"> ... </ace:dataTable>
```

with CSS class:

```
.my-width {
    width:80%
}
```

As a side note, when you are ready to try out the latest Primefaces [`<p:dataTable>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableHome.jsf), you will find [many attributes](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/dataTable.html) designed for setting up proper CSS styles.

Comment: I already mentioned that it is not working in case when we squeez the table.Let say , Create a table of four columns and set header name `Service number` for all of them.Now you can maximize the width of the table but can't minimize.Try it